# How to get the name of the user who executed a bash script as sudo?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sudo, users

I want to create a bash script that must be executed with sudo but should take into account the name of the non-sudo user who executed it. So if user `bob` runs `sudo ./myscript.sh` I would like `myscript.sh` to know `bob` was the one who executed it.

Let's look inside `myscript.sh`:

```
USER=$(whoami)
# Do something that takes into account the username.
```

How can I know the name of the user who spawned the process? More specifically, what should I use instead of `whoami` to get `bob` and not `root`?

Comment: That's not a valid script, I think you meant `USER=$(whoami)`. Note that the `USER` already exists as a shell internal variable. Also, if it's a bash script, **don't** run it using `sh`, which only has a POSIX-compatible subset of features.

Comment: why not edit? fixed now.

Comment: It's too trivial, edits need to be at least 6 characters, at least suggested ones.

Comment: ok, I understand. Thanks for the tips :D I usually put a hashbang like this `#!/usr/bin/env bash` on my bash scripts.

Comment: The hashbang is ignored if you call it explicitly with `sh` or something else.

Comment: I meant I use the mentioned hashbang and execute the script with dot `./script.sh` :D

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I'm not sure how standard it is, but at least in Ubuntu systems `sudo` sets the following environment variables (among others - see the `ENVIRONMENT` section of the sudo manpage):

```
   SUDO_UID        Set to the user ID of the user who invoked sudo

   SUDO_USER       Set to the login of the user who invoked sudo
```

for example,

```
steeldriver@lap-t61p:~$ sudo sh -c 'whoami'
root
steeldriver@lap-t61p:~$ sudo sh -c 'echo $SUDO_USER'
steeldriver
```

Comment: Works as expected on all platforms I tested: debian, fedora(redhat) and freebsd. Thanks!

Comment: Confirmed working on a Mac.

Comment: Works on ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 10):

If you want it to work without `sudo` as well, use `${SUDO_USER:-$USER}`. For example:

```
printf '%s\n' "${SUDO_USER:-$USER}"
```

`${var:-val}` will expand to `$var`, unless it's unset or empty, in which case it will expand to `val`.