# Can a script be executed without the username being logged by $USER or $SUDO_USER

Tags: bash, shell-script, users

I'm trying to find out if its possible to execute a Bash script by another user or way than the user who is logged in or by `sudo -u otherusername`.

I have a script with line: `echo $USER`.
`echo $SUDO_USER` this should always show me the user that executed that script.

From [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137175/377345) I gathered that some user could use `sudo` and so the variable `SUDO_USER` or `${SUDO_USER:-$USER}` could show which user executed a Bash script whether invoked by the logged in user or an user using `sudo`.

I cannot think of another way to execute a Bash script than with a logged in user or with `sudo`. So is there another way to execute a script than the above mentioned methods and would the command `echo $USER` or `echo ${SUDO_USER:-$USER}` then be showing the "original" username?

In other words is it possible to hide your username from `$USER` or `$SUDO_USER` when executing a script?

I searched for it on the internet but i did not find any answer, search keywords used: "bash invoke script obfuscating username".

Probably the answer is no but since anything is possible... some hack or spoof of some sort is maybe possible...

Comment: Are you aware that `sudo` can run commands as _any_ user, not just as root? is that an acceptable solution or do you need this to happen in systems with no `sudo` installed? Also, what operating system is this about?

Comment: The question is unclear. What do you want to achieve? If it's just that `echo $USER` shows a different value, you can set the environment variable `USER`. This does not change anything about the program's privileges, it just changes the value of the variable. If you actually want to run as a different user, then why not use sudo? What do you call “the correct username”? With multiple users involved, there isn't a single user name.

Comment: @terdon I'm using Debian 10, sudo is installed and i did not know that the target user would be recorded in the $USER variable when sudo -u username would be used. My goal is to catch the original user using sudo or not using sudo. I guess i need to do some more digging into sudo.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' 'SO- stop being evil' What i mean with correct username is the original user invoking the script whether he's using sudo or not.

Comment: In the sudo case, do you mean the user who ran sudo or the user that sudo switched to? And either way, what do you want to do with this information?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' 'SO- stop being evil' I updated my question to make it more clear hopefully. I understand that with $USER and $SUDO_USER i can find the user who ran sudo and the user that sudo switched to. What i would like to know is if its possible to run a script and hiding your username from $USER or $SUDO_USER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sudo` to run commands as any user (as long as you have `sudo` access):

```
$ cat ~/scripts/foo.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $USER

$ ~/scripts/foo.sh
terdon

terdon@tpad ~ $ sudo -u bib ~/scripts/foo.sh
bib
```

So just run your script with `sudo -u USERNAME` where `USERNAME` is the user name of the target user.

The `SUDO_USER` variable has the username of the user who ran the `sudo` command, but the `USER` variable will be the target user:

```
$ cat ~/scripts/foo.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "sudo command was run by $SUDO_USER but I am actually $USER"


$ sudo -u bib ~/scripts/foo.sh
sudo command was run by terdon but I am actually bib
```

Comment: Thank you
Would there be a variable or a way to find the user who used sudo and the target user?

Comment: @smj what do you mean? That's what the second script is showing you: `SUDO_USER` is the user who used `sudo` and `USER` is the target user.

Comment: I think you are right but my question is if there's another way to invoke a script which is not logged by the USER or SUDO_USER variable ? I think i will edit my question better.

Comment: @smj yes, please edit and clarify. And what should happen if I ssh into a machine as `terdon`, then use `su -` to become `root`, then use `su bob` to become `bob`. Who is the "logged in" user now? What would you expect to see? Basically, why does it matter who is logged in? Is it to know what settings/files will be read or is it to track suers for security?

Comment: It is to track users to see who executed the script, so for security. I like your example it could involve three different users to be tracked. I would expect to see bob as USER and root as SUDO_USER. Ultimately I would need to know who ssh'd into the machine as that is the user who needs to be identified. I guess some ssh.log or auth.log parsing would be needed to be done.

Comment: @smj yes, this is a _completely_ different question then. I suggest you ask a new question and explain what you want to achieve. I can hop through a hundred different users before running the final `sudo` command, and you will never know that. You would need to track who is logging in, you can't do it the way you're thinking.

Comment: ok, thank you. The new question i should post is how to log the original user who executed a script. I shall dig a bit deeper into the matter first before to post a new question. Your answers helped me to see that there's probably a ton of possible scenarios. So i should start building the script with what i know already and see from there. So existing scenario's are ssh, multiple su's, $USER, $SUDO_USER.

Comment: Sounds good yes. Just be sure to explain what you are trying to achieve, @smj, and not only the approach you are thinking (here you just mentioned `sudo` but didn't explain _why_ you want this, what the final objective is). That way you can avoid the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: ok thanks for the tips. Yes i agree the explanation should be better. It wasn't clear in my head and hadn't tried enough the several options. From what i found now is that probably an external server for auditing could be the answer but it is a long shot. There's no short answer or solution to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering the question as asked. But please beware that the way this question is worded makes me think you don't understand how the system works, and using this answer without caution is likely to result in an insecure system.

> From the link above i gathered that some user could use SUDO and so the variable SUDO_USER or ${SUDO_USER:-$USER} could show which user executed a Bash script whether invoked by the logged in user or an user using SUDO.

The part about sudo is true, the part about not using sudo isn't. If you have a sudoers rule like

```
@staff ALL = (priya) /usr/local/bin/myprogram
```

then when `myprogram` runs, it can be confident that if the program was invoked through this sudo rule, then the `SUDO_USER` variable is set to the user who invoked `sudo myprogram`. A corollary is that if `SUDO_USER` is not set, then the whoever ran `myprogram` had some other ways to access the user account that `myprogram` is running as.

As a consequence, if `myprogram` is supposed to take some action on behalf of another user, and the only way to access the `priya` account for non-administrators is through this rule, then `myprogram` can securely access priya's resources on behalf of the user indicated by `SUDO_USER`.

If `myprogram` is running without elevated privileges, then whoever ran it can choose how they run it. They can set whatever environment variables they like. The `USER` variable is a convention, it has no relevance to security. But anyway, if `myprogram` is running without elevated privileges, it can trust `USER` if it wants to. Security requires elevated privileges. If you wanted to ship an executable program as a black box and check that only certain users can run it, forget it: that's impossible, and anyone who claims otherwise is selling snake oil.

> In other words is it possible to hide your username from $USER or $SUDO_USER when executing a script?

That's not the same question! As I explained above, it's absolutely trivial to set `USER` and `SUDO_USER` when running a script. There is one case where it isn't, which is if the user is *running sudo and telling it to run a script* (as opposed to running the script directly). Only in that case, assuming a default sudo configuration, `USER` is guaranteed to be the user running the script and `SUDO_USER` is guaranteed to be the user who invoked sudo.

Note that if what happens is a sudo rule that invokes program1 which in turns invokes program2, program2 can only trust these variables if it trusts program1 not to change them.

> I cannot think of another way to execute a Bash script than with a logged in user or with SUDO.

Any other service that invokes programs. A very common one is [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Typically a user logs in and edits a crontab; but after that, the cron job runs without the user being “logged in” in the sense of being in front of the computers or having entered credentials. The user is “logged in” inasmuch as cron counts as a login (which is a matter of terminology).

There are also other ways to invoke a program with a different account, for example [su](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_(Unix)) (which requires credentials for the target account) and [pkexec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/pkexec.1.html) (which normally requires credentials for the target account, but more complex policies are possible). Or the program can be running inside a namespace or container of some kind (there are too many kinds to list here).

Under Linux, there's also a concept of [“loginuid”](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/audit_setloginuid.3.html). This value is supposed to be set when the user logs in and does not change when the user changes to another account. For example, `su -` or `sudo -i` follows the normal process for logging in a user (setting limits, invoking `.profile`, etc.), but they do not change the loginuid. You can retrieve the loginuid from `/proc/self/loginuid` or with the [`logname`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logname.1.html) command. This is mainly intended for auditing. Note that by default, root *can* change the loginuid. Note also that the loginuid is a per-process concept, there is no global concept of a single logged-in user.