# If I am writing a bash script to be run as sudo, how do I ensure I stay in the user shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a bash script to handle the installation of a repository, mostly it checks some basic dependencies and calls git clone often.

When running this script I want to perform a check to whether files have been installed or not.

```
git clone https://github.com/reticulatedpines/magiclantern_simplified.git 
echo "Exit status: ($?)" 
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Magic Lantern has been cloned into ${ML_PATH}."
else
    exit 1
fi
```

The problem is that the repository will clone into whatever the present working directory is which is not what I want and if I try `cd ~` to return to the home directory it actually sends me to the root shell:

```
root@debian:~# (repository installs here).
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: It is fairly common practice to assume that the working directory should not need to be changed, and then instead `cd` to the correct directory before executing the script. Most standard command act like this. If you know what the absolute path is to the working directory, you could use that in the script, e.g. `cd ~theuser/the/dir`.  I believe the missing piece of info in the question is where you tell us exactly how you run your script (via root's cron, or via `sudo`, or in some other manner).

Comment: in `[ $? -eq 0 ]`, you're checking the exit status of `[` which will be successful if `echo` succeeded. Use `if git...; then echo success; else echo "failure (status = $?"; fi`

Comment: This may be relevant: [How to get the name of the user who executed a bash script as sudo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137217)

Comment: Why would you clone a source code repository as `root`? `root` is to make administrative tasks, not development, not compiling code. Only a `make install` or equivalent as the last stage after building might need to be made as `root` if it needs to install files in system locations or more generally needs to make changes to the system.

Comment: I do check dependencies in the script which require apt install and as far as I know this can only be done in sudo, but then again maybe it should be a separate script... still I would like this one script to handle everything for setting up this project. Thanks for your suggested edit.

Comment: You do not want to run a script like this as root.  If -- big IF -- you must do privileged things within your script, then only do those very specific things with privilege.  For example, run your script as a regular user, but use "sudo apt install" within the script if it's a must.  I would still recommend against it.  It's just bad practice to do everything on a system as root and in many, many cases it's completely unnecessary.  Unfortunately the linux culture has evolved in a way where people think they must do everything with sudo.

Comment: Okay will follow this advice and look into what I can use.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -E <cmd>
```

running sudo with -E " preserve user environment when running command"

Preserving the user environment will run the command in the current location.